# Creating a draft via gmail api results with invalid_grant error - proper scopes are provided

Tags: gmail-api

I'm getting `invalid_grant` error when creating a draft.
Scopes I requested:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly 
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ 
https://mail.google.com/ 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

I use python library to interact with Gmail API (
The main problem is that this sometimes works as expected, sometimes it doesn't work and I don't know why.
My code look like the one from example here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-advertisers-api/FZo-6ZZGeyQ), the possible problems that cause invalid_grant errors are if your server's clock is out of sync with NTP and/or you've exceeded the refresh token limit. This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google) also suggested to make sure that you specify `access_type=offline` in your request.

Here's a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434442/5832311) for a checklist of potential causes for the problems:

> 1. Server clock/time is out of sync
> 2. Not authorized for offline access
> 3. Throttled by Google
> 4. Using expired refresh tokens
> 5. User has been inactive for 6 months
> 6. Use service worker email instead of client ID
> 7. Too many access tokens in short time
> 8. Client SDK might be outdated
> 9. Incorrect/incomplete refresh token
> 10. User has actively revoked access to our app
> 11. User has reset/recovered their Google password

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it was connected with refreshing the token.