# How to use Jmeter response parameter for another request input parameter

Tags: jmeter

1. I want to use response, refresh_token value as next request input parameter.

[image: Response body parameter]

2. I added Regular Expression Extractor there.

[image: Regular Expression extractor]

3. I called for regular expression extractor parameter as below on next request.

[image: Call parameter]

4. But still getting invalid refresh token error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a checklist of things to check for the error you are getting.

[Using Refresh Token Exception { "error" : "invalid_grant" }'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724003/using-refresh-token-exception-error-invalid-grant)

Hope it helps.

I think the issue might be with the missing bearer type prefix, try extracting the bearer type as well

Information won from the following source:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re

Comment: I am still checking for the one user verification. Yes. According to that list  the reason may be 1. Refresh Token is not valid anymore or 
2. Refresh Token is wrong. Unable to find the issue of the regular expression. Thank you

Comment: Maybe passing along the bearer type will work, please see the link in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You have use regular expression to fetch data from "Response Message". Instead, you need it from "Body". Change "Field to Check" from "Response Message" to "Body" in regular expression extractor.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked. but still error is appearing. Unable to trigger the error point.

Comment: I have changed this too. Finally it get works. Thank you

Comment: @ChamaniThakshila if it helped you can accept the answer,see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers..Whichever answer helped you..I think DMitri answer is having a lot of info..that is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to use `access_token`, not the `refresh_token`. [Refresh Tokens](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg06687.html) are required only when your access token is expired as requesting a new **access_token** using the `refresh_token` is a way faster and easier than doing full authentication.

Also be aware that it's better to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to deal with JSON data, the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query will be as simple as

```
$.access_token
```

See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article for more information if needed.

Comment: I need refresh_token for the next request and it is working fine if I enter that value manually for the parameter without considering regular expression.

Comment: In this case move your Regular Expression Extractor to be **a child** of the `oauthtoken` request as JMeter PostProcessors obey [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) and the value simply gets overwritten by the next request. And switch it to read from **Response Body**